# loop is cut one element of the array

Tags: java, arrays

The problem is :

> Write a program that reads a number n and then declares an array of n elements. The program then fills the array with the first n numbers, where each number is two to the power of the previous. Finally, display array’s contents.

My code :

```
import java.util.*;

public class Q1 {
  static Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

  public static void main(String args [] ) {
    int num;
    int i = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter a number :");
    num = scan.nextInt();

    double [] a=new double[num];
    a[0]= num ;

    for ( ;i<=a.length-1 ; i++) {
      a[i+1] = Math.pow(2,a[i]);

      System.out.println((int)(a[i]) );
    }
  }
}
```

The error is :

```
   ----jGRASP exec: java Q1

Enter a number :
4
4
16
65536
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at Q1.main(Q1.java:16)

 ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
```

why it says that?
And the number by user printed twice!

Comment: I had a homework assignment like this once.

Comment: your error may be occuring at this line a[i+1] = Math.pow(2,a[i])

Comment: Yeah sure, I'll send it right on over

Answer (score 6):

```
 a[i+1] = Math.pow(2,a[i]); // issue here
```

When `i=a.length-1`, `i+1` is `a.length`. So there is no index value match in this array.

Suggestion:

Create an array witch has `lenght= a.length+1`

```
double powArray[] =new double[a.length+1];
```

Now

```
powArray[0]=a[0];
for(int i=1;i<powArray.length;i++){
   powArray[i]=Math.pow(2,a[i-1]);
}
```

Comment: @Walaa you can get idea from my answer

Answer (score 1):

Issue is on line.16 as per compiler : `a[i+1] = Math.pow(2,a[i]);` The problem is indexes are not properly matched here.So it gives ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception.Here `i=a.length-1, i+1=a.length`.So it is giving  ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception.

You should check that your index is not negative and not higher than the array length before accessing an array item.

Refer this : [Avoiding index out of bounds exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701861/avoiding-index-out-of-bounds-exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

Concentrate on below portion of your code, its easy and you'll feel good if you figure out yourself:

```
for ( ;i<=a.length-1 ; i++) // check from where i starts and where it ends
{
     a[i+1] = Math.pow(2,a[i]); // check what value of i would be here on each iteration    
     System.out.println((int)(a[i]) );
}
```

Also you could use a debugger and check every iteration

Answer (score 0):

Few things to look upon here.

You have written `a[0]= num ;` which means the first value in the array is the same as the number entered by the user. Thus, you can see the number printed again. Thus,

```
a[0] = 1; // initial value has to be 1, contrary to what you've used
```

Next, your loop to generate the array values needs to be fixed. When you have `i+1`, the array index goes out of bounds in the last iteration, where your `i is a.length - 1`. Thus change your loop to something like this

```
for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i] = Math.pow(2, a[i-1]);
}
```

Now, print the array values in a separate loop, as the previous loop won't print the value of the first index of the array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    System.out.println((int)a[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the upper limit to a.length-2 .Rest code remain same

```
import java.util.*;

public class Q1 {
  static Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

  public static void main(String args [] ) {
    int num;
    int i = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter a number :");
    num = scan.nextInt();

    double [] a=new double[num];
    a[0]= num ;

    for ( ;i<=a.length-2 ; i++) {
      a[i+1] = Math.pow(2,a[i]);

      System.out.println((int)(a[i]) );
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        int num ;
        System.out.println("Enter a number :");
        num = scan.nextInt();
        double [] a=new double[num];
        a[0]= num ; //Assign First Element To Array
        double prev = a[0];
        for(int i=1;i<a.length;i++){
            a[i] = Math.pow(2,prev);
            prev = a[i];
        }
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
            System.out.println(a[i]);
```

**Output**

```
    Enter a number :
    3

    3.0
    8.0
    256.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the loop to :

for(;i ***<*** a.length-1;i++)

since when you assign 4 as a length for a[]..

you have a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]... 4 slots.

Now a.length gives 4.

so for your a[i+1] for i=a.length-1 (i.e 3 ) .. a[i+1] = a[4]... which is out of the array bound for you array.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Q1 {
  static Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

  public static void main(String args [] ) {
    int num;
    int i = 0;
    System.out.println("Enter a number :");
    num = scan.nextInt();

    double [] a=new double[num];

    for ( ;i<a.length ; i++) {
      a[i] = Math.pow(2,i);

      System.out.pri``nt((int)a[i]+ " ");
    }
  }
}
```